# RxJS - Wait until 5 events to occur before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have a simple RxJS5 observable like so:

```
function foo(){

 return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
          obs.next();
   });

}
```

the observable is created like so:

```
const x = foo();

function bar(){

     return someObs()
       .flatMap(() => x.wait(5))  // wait for x to fire 5 times
       .map(v => ({z:v}));

}
```

What I want to do is wait for 5 events in the x observable to fire, before continuing.

I don't think the `take` operator is what I want, so I just called the operator "`wait`"

How can I do that with RxJS5?

Comment: I tried takeLast, and that didn't seem to work

Comment: .takeLast(1) might work, but it will have to be in combination with something else, and I don't know what that something else is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator you are looking for is [skip](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skip)

```
 return someObs()
   .skip(5)
   .map(v => ({z:v}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I can do this:

```
 return this.obsEnqueue.take(5).takeLast(1);
```

because I ultimately only want to fire 1 event, 
after waiting for 5 events

If there is a better way to do this, would sure like to hear about it